# How to add a constant column with conditions while doing inner join in SQL

Tags: python, sql-server

I have two tables table1 and table2 with ids in bot tables

I want to have target column based on table2 IDs , when joining I need to add 1 for target if we have ids in both tables else 0 .

```
SELECT a.*,b.* , target as (CASE WHEN b.client_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
 FROM table1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN table2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ID = b.client_id
```

I have achieve this in pandas.

```
table2_list = table2['client_id'].tolist()

table1['target'] = table1['ID'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x in table2_list else 0)
```

Comment: Stop littering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) until you understand the consequences, anticipate and handle the problems, and have a GOOD reason for using it

Answer (score 1):

Case When conditions should be boolean value, like b.client_id > 0
column target could be

**... as [target]**
or
[target] = ...

```sql
select 1 as ID, 'C-1' as C1
into #t1;
select 1 as client_id, 'C-2' as C2
into #t2;

SELECT *
, (CASE WHEN b.client_id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as [target]
FROM #t1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #t2 b WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON a.ID = b.client_id;

-- or
SELECT *
,[target]= (CASE WHEN b.client_id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
FROM #t1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #t2 b WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON a.ID = b.client_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

With an INNER JOIN you won't know, by definition. Try a LEFT JOIN and check for Nulls.

```
SELECT a.*,b.* , target as (CASE WHEN b.client_id is NUll THEN 0 ELSE 1 END )
 FROM table1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN table2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ID = b.client_id
```